# In Android, what is context ( one of the parameter in toast)why we use this keyword as context?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Android, what is context ( one of the parameter in toast)why we use this keyword as context? plz explain

i have tried on google but not getting answer.. i m using kotlin language in android.

Comment: Context is a class defined by the Android SDK.  It isn't a keyword-  it's a type.  If you're seeing `somevas as Context` that's casting a variable into a Context.  Which is something that would be very odd to do.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_(computing)) ,  a context is the minimal set of data for a task to run.

In some programming architecture， a context always acts the role of an environment which linking up-stream and down-stream (or back-end and front-end).

In android, a [Context](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Context.java;l=110?q=context.java&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) is the interface to global information about an application environment.The global information includes resources and apis to get system services(`getSystemService(..)`).
A context contains the necessay environment for an app to do something.

The android's contex may be an Activity, a Service, or an Application.

For a `Toast`, it needs a context to get text from `Resources` and get a system service (`NotificationManager`) to show the text.